# eslint VSCode error on the fist line of all my TypeScript files

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have just converted my Angular project from tslint to eslint.

All seem to be working fine, except I have the following error on the start of each file

[image]

I added the following to my `.eslint` , but it made no difference.

```
    "valid-jsdoc": "off",
    "check-alignment": "off",
```

I currently have "eslint": "^7.32.0"

Aside - Version 8 was causing the [following issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73103416/vscode-eslint-reports-unknown-options-typescript-format-semicolons-javascript), so have downgraded to 7, which got rid of that one.

What is causing the error as shown here?

### Update 1

I have the following eslint related packages.

```
"@angular-eslint/builder": "14.0.2",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.2",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.0.2",
"@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.0.2",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.0.2",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.29.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.29.0",
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
```

I have the following lint setup in angular.json

```
"lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": [
          "src/**/*.ts",
          "src/**/*.html"
        ]
      }
    }
```

When I run `ng lint` I get

```
  1:1    error    Definition for rule 'jsdoc/check-alignment' was not found                                                      jsdoc/check-alignment
```

for every single file.

The only way to get rid of the errors is in .eslintrc to add:

```
"jsdoc/check-alignment": "off",
```

Even if I set:

```
"jsdoc/check-alignment": "warn",
```

it still shows as an error (not a warning).

For now, I have set it to `off`, but it would be good to know how to fix it (so I could then enabled it as a warning, and it would pick up real mis-alignments).

Comment: In order to disable a rule, you must reference the full rule name, in your case `"jsdoc/check-alignment": "off",`. Also since this errors come from the plugin `eslint-plugin-jsdoc`, which version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: Additionally, does this error also occur when you run the linter from the command line? If not, it could be just a caching issue or plugin misconfiguration.

Comment: @JSONDerulo - yes I get it when I run the command line. You are correct if I use `jsdoc/check-alignment": "off"` I can get rid of the error. I don't seem to have  any `eslint-plugin-jsdoc` installed (perhaps it is part of another related (package)? I Have added some more info to the question under [UPDATE1]